# Yii2 UploadedFile saveAs() error handling

Tags: yii2

I have a controller action that accepts a file upload via ajax request and saves basic info about the file.  If the save was successful, it then executes saveAs() to actually save the file to the filesystem.  A little something like this:

```
if ($model->save()) {
    $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
}
```

Everything works great but I'd like to implement a check around the saveAs() so I can delete the just-inserted-record if the file, for some reason, can't be saved.  I see that [UploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html) has a `$hasError` and `$errors` but if there is a problem saving the file code execution seems to stop at the saveAs(), not moving past it to actually let me handle the error.

Is there a way for me to catch saveAs() errors and perform some logic if there is a problem saving?

**EDIT**

I have tried assigning the return variable as in the following.  However, this is how I first noticed that if a saveAs() error occurs, no code gets executed past the saveAs().

```
$saveResult = $file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
// Any code down here won't be executed if (for example)
// that "uploads" directory doesn't exist and the saveAs() fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code throws an exception (directory not exist, not writable, etc.), you can use a regular try - catch block to handle that:

```
try {
    $file->saveAs(...);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

Read official PHP docs about [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Another alternative is to add checks to prevent all most common possible errors:

```
if (!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
    ...
}
```

if such directory not exist, etc.

To get rid of that, I'd recommend to write tests and create that folders in deploy script (if they not exist).

Comment: The try/catch didn't work.  I temporarily changed the permissions of the upload directory and ran that line of code (with the try/catch) and though there was an error, the code inside the catch was never executed.  So, it seems that even though an error can occur, the result of that saveAs() is still true.

Comment: @justinvoelker What kind of error you get? Could you write its message?

Comment: Completely stupid on my part.  There are two potential points for failure in this particular script: creating a subdirectory if needed, and saving the image to it.  I was changing the permissions of the parent directory to test that the saveAs failed and that's where I was determining that it wasn't working.  However, the script was never getting that far having failed on the mkdir earlier in the script.  I changed how I was testing this and sure enough, the try/catch worked.  It just wasn't being given a chance to try/catch anything with the particular way I was testing.  Thanks!